# What happened to the "Merge Vertices" that existed in version 2.82 Edit Mode - Vertex drop-down menu?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices

Version confirmed with existing option: 2.82.7,
Versions confirmed to omit previously existing option: 2.91.2, 2.93.0 Alpha,

Steps to reproduce:

1. Load: Factory Defaults,
2. Select: Cube,
3. Switch to: Edit Mode,
4. Select: All,
5. Left Mouse Click: Vertex (Menu drop down),

Newer versions do not have the "Merge Vertices" option in the drop down menu, while key pressing "M" does still invoke the option as before.
As a beginner, I always use the drop-down menu options as I slowly learn shortcut keys, as such, it is best to have as many options available in the menus.
So, is this an ill-fated new feature or bug?

Comment: It should be vertex > merge and then there are a few options